# Looking for a first and last class for grouping items with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is slightly different from the traditional method for get first and last method, so I am asking expert help.

I will explain with code sample

My code structure is

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
</div>
```

When I use a jquery method like below

```
$('div.group-a:first').addClass('first');
$('div.group-a:last').addClass('last');
```

Result is like

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="group-a first"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a last"></div>
</div>
```

But I want the result should be like below with first and last class for each group.

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="group-a first"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a last"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-a first"></div>
<div class="group-a"></div>
<div class="group-a last"></div>
```

Is it possible with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Yes my code structure is like above, unfortunately I can't made any change for it because its coming from an external plugin

Comment: I want to share one more information after reviewing below answers. My code structure not a static one there are chance to came many div's with different class like group-a, group-b, group-c, group-d etc. So I am looking a dynamic solution like below BoltClock's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Why iterate through the classes when you can use CSS adjacent sibling selectors and `:not`?   Here's a much cleaner method!

```
// adding first
$(':not(.group-a) + .group-a, .group-a:first').addClass('first');

// adding last
$('.group-a:last').addClass('last');
$('.group-a + :not(.group-a)').prev().addClass('last');
```

Note that this works for any number of `group-a` and `group-b`, and for other classes such as `group-c`, as requested.  The `prev()` is needed because for the CSS adjacency selector, only the second element, not the first, may be selected.  Hope this helps!

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v3kb8/2/)**

Answer (score 4):

The naïve way would be to [iterate through each `.group-a` element](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/PqNC4) and check if it's either the first child or comes directly after a `.group-b`, and if it's either the last child or comes directly before a `.group-b`:

```
$('div.group-a').each(function() {
    var t = $(this);

    if (t.is(':first-child, div.group-b + div')) {
        t.addClass('first');
    }

    if (t.is(':last-child') || t.next('div.group-b').length > 0) {
        t.addClass('last');
    }
});
```

You'll need to use the `.next()` method to check its next sibling because there isn't a selector for matching an element that precedes another.

([You can use `.prev()` in lieu of the `+` selector if you like your `if` statements to be congruent.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/PqNC4/1))

Adapting it for any number of groups as long as you're only looking for `.group-a` elements is easy, just replace `.group-b` with `:not(.group-a)`:

```
    if (t.is(':first-child, div:not(.group-a) + div')) {
        t.addClass('first');
    }

    if (t.is(':last-child') || t.next('div:not(.group-a)').length > 0) {
        t.addClass('last');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Hope it will sort out my issue, I'll post a replay once I tried out it.

Answer (score 3):

Updated

```
function colorFirstLast(thisClass){
    $('div').find("."+thisClass).each(function () {
        var node = $(this);
        var prevNode = node.prev();
        var nextNode = node.next();
        if (prevNode == undefined || !prevNode.hasClass(thisClass)) {
            node.addClass('first');
        }
        if (nextNode == undefined || !nextNode.hasClass(thisClass)) {
            node.addClass('last');
        }
    });
}

colorFirstLast('group-a');
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDHqH/2/)

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use regular expressions to match whole class names. Use `.hasClass()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Is there something wrong with wrapping the groups together and then just using first and last for each group?

```
<div class="wrap">
<div>
    <div class="group-a first"></div>
    <div class="group-a"></div>
    <div class="group-a"></div>
    <div class="group-a last"></div>
</div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div class="group-b"></div>
<div>
    <div class="group-a first"></div>
    <div class="group-a"></div>
    <div class="group-a last"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't made any change for the code structure because its coming from an external plugin

Answer (score 2):

A method would be to use the `.prev` method:

```
$(".group-a:first").addClass("first");  // the normal one
$(".group-a:last").addClass("last");    // the normal one


$(".group-b:first").prev(".group-a").addClass("last");  // the `.group-a` which is followed by the first `.group-b`

$(".group-b + .group-a").addClass("first"); // the `.group-a` whose previous element is `.group-b`
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/SFu8t/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can get the groups by filtering the consecutive elements having class group-a

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HK7n/)**

```
arr = [];
groupDivs = $('.wrap div')
groupDivs.each(function(index){   
   if(this.className == 'group-a') 
       arr.push($(this));
    if(this.className != 'group-a' || index == groupDivs.length-1)
    {
        if(arr.length > 0)
            arr[0].addClass('first');
        if(arr.length > 1)
            arr[arr.length-1].addClass('last');        
        arr.length = 0;
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".group-a:eq(0), .group-b + .group-a")
.addClass("first")
.addBack()
.find(".group-a:eq(-1), .group-a:eq(3)")
.addClass("last")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/jF868/