# How can I add classes to elements in a series by index?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Actually I am trying to create a list with alternative classes which should have a start and end class to each set of items for example I have following code

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-b"></div>
  <div class="item-b"></div>
  <div class="item-b"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-b"></div>
  <div class="item-b"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item-a start"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a end"></div>
  <div class="item-b start"></div>
  <div class="item-b"></div>
  <div class="item-b end"></div>
  <div class="item-a start"></div>
  <div class="item-a"></div>
  <div class="item-a end"></div>
  <div class="item-b start"></div>
  <div class="item-b end"></div>
</div>
```

I saw [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776810/looking-for-a-first-and-last-class-for-grouping-items-with-javascript) but that's dependent on jQuery. I don't have jQuery in my scenario I wanted to achieve that with plain JavaScript.

I am working with react and having an array of object from the API with something like

```
arr = [
  {class:"left", id:"0", direction:0 },
  {class:"right", id:"1", direction:1 },
  {class:"right", id:"2", direction:1 },
  {class:"left", id:"3", direction:0 },
  {class:"left", id:"4", direction:0 },
  {class:"left", id:"5", direction:0 },
  {class:"right", id:"6", direction:1 },
  {class:"right", id:"7", direction:1 },
]
```

and loop through this to list items

I am trying to achieve with the for loop but no success

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show an attempt here.

Comment: Also, you may be asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Consider asking about your actual goal instead.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Just group related items in wrapper elements. The first item in that set of siblings is the first one and the last item in that set of siblings would be the last one. Or, just query for all the members of a single class (`.querySelectorAll()`) and then look at the item at index 0 as the first and the item at index length -1 to find the last one.

Comment: What happens if a sequence only has one element?

Comment: @charlietfl that will add "start end" both classes

Comment: @ScottMarcus we don't know the length of items, actually I am trying to  group it up with start and end class, updated question

Comment: Now that you have added that you are working with react you should be parsing the data array and not the elements in the dom

Comment: You don't need to know the length. That's the point. You get that dynamically, by getting all the elements into an collection and then you get the length of the collection.

Comment: @dippas This is not an nth child issue since the same classes get repeated in different parts of the list

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first. There is an error in the array of objects: you put:

id='0',

instead of:

id:'0'.

Now, to give each element their respective class in the array, use this.

```js
  var arr = [
    {class:"left", id:"0" },
    {class:"right", id:"1" },
    {class:"right", id:"2" },
    {class:"left", id:"3" },
    {class:"left", id:"4" },
    {class:"left", id:"5" },
    {class:"right", id:"6" },
    {class:"right", id:"7" },
  ]
  var cArr = Array.from(document.querySelector(".wrap").children);
  //converts NodeList into Array just in case
  for(var i in cArr) {
    //loops elements
    if(arr[i] === undefined || arr[i].class === undefined) continue;
    //makes sure object in arr is defined
    cArr[i].classList.add(arr[i].class);
    //gives element specified class in arr
    console.log(cArr[i]);
    //console logs the element to make sure the class was added
  }
```

```js
var arr = [
        {class:"left", id:"0" },
        {class:"right", id:"1" },
        {class:"right", id:"2" },
        {class:"left", id:"3" },
        {class:"left", id:"4" },
        {class:"left", id:"5" },
        {class:"right", id:"6" },
        {class:"right", id:"7" },
    ]
    var cArr = Array.from(document.querySelector(".wrap").children);
    for(var i in cArr) {
      if(arr[i] === undefined || arr[i].class === undefined) continue;
        cArr[i].classList.add(arr[i].class);
      console.log(cArr[i]);
      
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>classes</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="item-a 1">1</div>
        <div class="item-a 2">2</div>
        <div class="item-a 3">3</div>
        <div class="item-a 4">4</div>
        <div class="item-b 5">5</div>
        <div class="item-b 6">6</div>
        <div class="item-b 7">7</div>
        <div class="item-a 8">8</div>
        <div class="item-a 9">9</div>
        <div class="item-a 10">10</div>
        <div class="item-b 11">11</div>
        <div class="item-b 12">12</div>
    </div>
    
    <script>

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: couldn't get what you are trying to explain